# Keep a list of strings for every thread

Tags: c, multithreading, daemon

I am developing a multi-threaded socket listener (daemon) .

I succesefully implemented multi threading using pthread library.

When the device connects to the daemon it send's an identification number my question is:

How to store that identification number for every thread so when i receive some data from that device to know it's ID.

In delphi is something called threadvar ( a variable that is allocated for every thread ).If that is not possible is there a library I can use to store lists? I am not planing to reinvent the weel ( eg make my own linked list )

I use GNUCC on Linux Mint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to answer if we had you code but :

- If you want a thread local variable with pthread, just allocate it on the stack of the function
  which is run in a thread (This thread local variable would be a pointer to your list of strings).
- You can use [Glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/) which has singly and doubly linked lists to store your strings. Make sure you free the list at the end of the function which is run in a thread
- You can pass data to the function which will is threaded through a `void *` pointer (It is unclear if you need to do that though)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for thread specific data to store variables; then have a look in to pthread_setspecific() and pthread_getspecific().